# Searching - Stored Procedure - DateTime variable - Easy Resolution?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that when entered the three variables:

```
 @Bank_Number = 530 
 @Branch_Number = 002
 @Date_From = 10/28/2014
 @Date_To  = 10/29/2014
```

It will return all records between the `Date_From` and `Date_To` dates that match the `Bank_Number` and `Branch_Number`.

The code I have here is incorrect slightly I'm not sure how to proceed.

[image: Table I'm Querying in my stored procedure]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Something_Proc] 
      @Bank_Number varchar(3),
      @Branch_Number varchar(3),
      @Date_From datetime,
      @Date_To datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @bankNumber varchar(3) = @Bank_Number,
            @branchNumber varchar(3) = @Branch_Number,
            @dateCreated datetime = @Date_From,
            @dateCreated datetime = @Date_To 

    SELECT DISTINCT     
            A.bankNumber, 
            A.branchNumber, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), A.dateCreated, 1)
    FROM        
        dbo.(table from picture) A
    WHERE
        (@bankNumber IS NULL OR Bank_Number LIKE @bankNumber + '%')
        AND (@branchNumber IS NULL OR Branch_Number LIKE @branchNumber + '%')
        AND (@dateCreated  IS NULL OR (MONTH(dateCreated) = MONTH(@dateCreated) 
                                       AND DAY(dateCreated) = DAY(@dateCreated)
                                       AND YEAR(dateCreated) = YEAR(@dateCreated)))
END
```

Comment: Those are ***FOUR*** parameters ....

Comment: The dateCreated column is what I'm trying to reference with the Date_From and the Date_TO.

Comment: @marc_s sorry man I'm not thinking clearly after a certain point of fustration.

Comment: @jpw studio manager doesn't like it when I use CONVERT between Date_From and Date_To

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use something like this?

```
WHERE
    (@bankNumber IS NULL OR Bank_Number LIKE @bankNumber + '%')
    AND (@branchNumber IS NULL OR Branch_Number LIKE @branchNumber + '%')
    AND (@Date_From IS NULL OR @Date_From <= DateCreated)
    AND (@Date_To IS NULL OR DateCreated <= @DateTo)
```

Basically, either your `@Date_From` and `@Date_To` parameters are `NULL` (then that parameters isn't used in any way), or if it's not null, then it's used to compare `DateCreated` to be equal or larger than `@Date_From`, and equal or smaller than `@Date_To` ....

Comment: Sir, I appreciate your existence. 

if there is ever a point where you consider ending your miserable wretched existence. 

Please remember me. Thank you.